# VSCode bug with PyTorch DataLoader?

Tags: visual-studio-code, pytorch

The following code example works in Python, but **fails in VSCode in Linux** (but not VSCode in Windows).  I am wondering if there is something wrong with my code, or if there is something wrong with VSCode under Linux?

```
#Test of PyTorch DataLoader and Visual Studio Code
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader

class SimpleData(Dataset):
    """Very simple dataset"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = range(20)
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return self.data[idx]

if __name__ == '__main__':

    #Initialize DataLoader with above Dataset:
    dataloader = DataLoader(SimpleData(), batch_size=4, num_workers=1)

    print('Using DataLoader to show data in batches: ')
    for i, sample_batch in enumerate(dataloader):    #This fails in VSCode in Linux
        print('batch ', i, ':', sample_batch)

    print("--- Done ---")
```

The expected output is:

```
Using DataLoader to show data in batches:
batch  0 : tensor([0, 1, 2, 3])
batch  1 : tensor([4, 5, 6, 7])
batch  2 : tensor([ 8,  9, 10, 11])
batch  3 : tensor([12, 13, 14, 15])
batch  4 : tensor([16, 17, 18, 19])
--- Done ---
```

But with VSCode in Linux it hangs after printing the first line.

Comment: Have you tried with ```num_workers=0```? May be VS Code is not able to spawn a new process properly on linux.

Comment: @MohanaRao, that's it!  it works with `num_workers=0` !  That's a problem that's been dogging me for days!  Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome @Daniel Morris! Glad it helped.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you tried with `num_workers=0?`

May be VS Code is not able to spawn a new process properly on linux.