# T5Tokenizer and T5EncoderModel are used to encode sentences then nn.TransformerDecoder to decode to a 2-label tensor. It gives error

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers, pytorch-lightning, pytorch-dataloader, encoder-decoder

Used T5Tokenizer to tokenize a sentence then T5EncoderModel to encode. Finally, used the pytorch nn.TransformerDecoder to decode it. The target vector is a torch.tensor [y1, y2] where y1 and y2 have binary value. But it returns an error `RuntimeError: DataLoader worker (pid(s) 723820) exited unexpectedly`. The dataset class is given below.

```
tokenizer=T5TokenizerFast.from_pretrained('t5-base')
MAX_LEN = tokenizer(balanced_sentences[max_idx]).input_ids
class MyDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, sentences, labels):
        self.labels = labels
        self.sentences = sentences
        self.tokenizer = tokenizer
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.labels)
    
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        sentence = self.sentences[idx]
        label = self.labels[idx]
        tokenized = tokenizer(self.sentences[idx],
                             max_length=MAX_LEN,
                             padding='max_length', 
                             truncation=True,
                             add_special_tokens=True,
                             return_tensors="pt")
        sample = {"input_id": tokenized['input_ids'].flatten(), 
                  "attention_mask":tokenized['attention_mask'].flatten(), 
                  "label": label}
        return sample
```

The model is created in the following way

```
class MyModel(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.encoder = T5EncoderModel.from_pretrained("t5-base", return_dict = True)
        dec_layer = nn.TransformerDecoderLayer(d_model=512, nhead=8, batch_first=True)
        self.decoder = nn.TransformerDecoder(dec_layer, num_layers=6)
        self.loss_fc = nn.BCELoss()
        
    def forward(self, input_id, attention_mask, label=None):
        encoded_sentence = self.encoder(input_id, attention_mask)#.last_hidden_state.mean(dim=1) 
        loss, output = self.decoder(label, encoded_sentence)
        return loss, output
    
    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        input_id = batch['input_id']
        attention_mask = batch['attention_mask']
        label = batch['label']    
        loss, output = self(input_id = input_id,
                            attention_mask=attention_mask,
                             label = label)
        self.log('train_loss', loss, prog_bar = True, logger = True)
        return loss
    
    def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        input_id = batch['input_id']
        attention_mask = batch['attention_mask']        
        label = batch['label']    
        loss, output = self(input_id = input_id,
                            attention_mask=attention_mask,
                             label = label)
        self.log('train_loss', loss, prog_bar = True, logger = True)
        return loss
    
    def configure_optimizers(self):
        return torch.optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=0.001)

trainer = pl.Trainer(logger = logger, 
                     num_sanity_val_steps=0, 
                     max_epochs = N_EPOCHS, 
                     gpus = 1, 
                     progress_bar_refresh_rate = 20)

trainer.fit(model, data_module)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're use VSCode it sounds like the data loader has multiple workers and it can't create more threads. Set the number of workers to 0.

See: [VSCode bug with PyTorch DataLoader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53660465/vscode-bug-with-pytorch-dataloader)